# Is it possible to give a phone Call action to a UILabel?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, parse-platform, phone-call

I am fetching a String from Parse.com into a UILabel programmatically in my app.
The String is a phone number. So my question is, is it possible to give an action to the UILabel on click to make a Call.. or do I have to fetch the data from a Button, or better yet, is this possible?

If it is possible, how would should I go about? Does anyone have an example or tutorial I could follow?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You question is in two part :

1. Perform any kind on action when a UILabel is taped
2. Perform a phone call action (action used in the first part)

First, to perform an action when a label is taped, you have to add a tap gesture recognizer to this label :

```
phoneNumberLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = 
   [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(phoneNumberLabelTap)];
[phoneNumberLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Then you have to implement your phoneNumberLabelTap method :

```
 -(void)phoneNumberLabelTap
{
    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",phoneNumberLabel.text]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
    } else {
        UIAlertView * calert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Call facility is not available!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [calert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Great!! I have a slight little problem and I believe it is because I have this UILabel in a Subview (maybe?) I get an error of use of undeclared identifier.

Comment: Hey, me again.. I was wondering how would this work to open a website in safari and also open a page in Facebook? How would the string format go? Thanks :)!

Comment: Me again, never mind! Figured it out for Website.. now looking for Facebook!

Comment: My only interaction with Facebook was to log in with Parse and get some informations about the user. You should look for "Facebook URL scheme iOS" in SO, there are plenty of answers but I have never tried any of them, so I can't help you more with custom URL, sorry!

Comment: If you ever come across needing it:, I figured it out. Here is the code: `- (void)goFbPage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapFbPage{
    
    NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", label.text]];
    
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
    } else {
            make you alert here..
    
}`
 And remember you string has to follow this format:  fb://profile/thepageidnumber

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.0:

```swift
mobileLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.phoneNumberLabelTap))
mobileLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func phoneNumberLabelTap() {        
    let phoneUrl = URL(string: "telprompt:\(mobileLabel.text ?? "")")!

    if(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(phoneUrl)) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(phoneUrl)
    } else {
        Constants.ShowAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "Cannot place call", viewController: self, isFailed: false)
    }
}
```